# Spring Batch Job pods are still running after completion of job in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, kubernetes-helm

Pods in the Kubernetes cluster are still running after the job is done.
My assumption is that there might be a chance that Kubernetes re-schedule the pods to the other nodes and job was done on those nodes that is why it is showing Job done but how Spring will monitor re-schedule pods that is why it will again re-deploy the pods for the completion of the job.

So my question is, Do spring monitor the pods after re-scheduling the pods to other nodes

Or

If my assumption is pointless can you please suggest a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Re-Scheduling Pods is at a higher level of abstraction where Spring runs. Spring does not (and should not) monitor or (re)schedule pods. Make sure your Spring application context is correctly closed after your batch job is done.

Comment: I need some clarifications - 

1 - Can Kubernetes re-schedule the pods to the other node which is deployed by the spring batch job?

and if YES

2 - How will spring will know the job has been done on other nodes?

3 - Then this will cause continue running pods problems.

4 - Then what is the possible cause of continuing to run pods after the job is done?

Comment: 1. yes. 2. Spring Batch will know that through the centralized job repository 3. No, as mentioned in the answer, if the application context is correctly closed, the pod should terminate when the job is finished. 4. You must have a resource that is still running like a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for example that should be shutdown.